# How to use 'DataRange1D' in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

everyone! I want follow a video to create circles on the Google map by using Bokeh. There is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import(GMapPlot,GMapOptions,ColumnDataSource,Circle,PanTool,WheelZoomTool,BoxSelectTool,DataRange1d)

df=pd.read_csv('bikes_October18.csv') #read data from the csv file
df1=pd.DataFrame({'stations':df.start_station_name,'lat':df.start_station_latitude,'long':df.start_station_longitude})  
df2=df1.drop_duplicates(subset='stations')
df3=pd.concat([df.start_station_name,df.end_station_name],axis=0)
a=df3.value_counts()
df2['frequncy']=df2.stations.map(a)
GeoInfo=df2

map_options=GMapOptions(lat=55.95415,lng=-3.20277,map_type='roadmap',zoom=3)
api_key=Goole_APIKEY

plot=GMapPlot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(),
              map_options=map_options,api_key=api_key)
plot.add_tool(PanTool(),WheelZoomTool(),BoxSelectTool())
baseline=GeoInfo['frequncy'].min()-1.0
scale=3
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=GeoInfo['lat'].tolist(),
                                  long=GeoInfo['long'].tolist(),
                                  rad=[(i-baseline)/scale for i in GeoInfo['frequncy'].tolist()]))
circle=Circle(x="long",y='lat',size="rad",fill_color='orange',fill_alpha=0.3)
plot.add_glyph(source,circle)

output_file('Edinburgh_bike_stations.html')
show(plot)
```

However, there is an value error says"Invalid value for 'x_range', MapPlot ranges may only be Range1d, not data ranges". I don't know how to correct it. Can anyone help with this? By the way, I am not sure if I used API key correctly. I got my own API key from google but I didn't store it as environmental variable. I just directly call it as api_key='my key value'. I am not sure if it works. Any advice on this as well? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `DataRange1d` may not be used with `GMapPlot`. This is because, unlike regular Bokeh plots where Bokeh has complete control over the range start/end values, Google Map plots are different. In particular, Google maps absolutely control the start/end of the range values in order to always preserve the aspect-ratio. This is 100% incompatible with `DataRange1d` models, which is why they are disallowed for `GMapPlot`. You should configure `Range1d` objects instead.

```
plot=GMapPlot(x_range=Range1d(), y_range=Range1d(),
              map_options=map_options,api_key=api_key)
```

However, really, if you are using any reasonably recent version of Bokejh, you should use the more recent `gmap` function that takes care of all this for you. Described here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html#google-maps

Comment: @bigredot Thank you very much! I will try it again and see how it goes.